# Check if a method exists

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way I can test if a method exists in Objective-C?

I'm trying to add a guard to see if my object has the method before calling it.

Comment: There's also the question of whether this is the right approach in the first place, since Objective-C classes can respond to selectors that they haven't declared (via `- forwardInvocation:`).

Answer (score 195, accepted):

```
if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(methodName:withEtc:)]) {
   [obj methodName:123 withEtc:456];
}
```

Answer (score 74):

There is also the static message **instancesRespondToSelector:(SEL)selector**
You would call it like this:

```
[MyClass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(someMethod:withParams:)]
```

or like this:

```
[[myObject class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(someMethod:withParams:)]
```

This may be useful if you would like to call one constructor or another one depending on this (I mean, before having the instance itself).

Comment: What different of instancesRespondToSelector from respondsToSelector ?

Comment: The main difference is that one is an instance message (to test if a determined instance message does exist) while the other is a class message (to test if a determined class message does exist).

Comment: +1 For [MyClass instancesRespondToSelector]. I needed it inside a init creation method: When subclassing maybe is necessary to call one super init method instead of others (deprecated ones), since self has not been created yet and respondsToSelector will always return NO.

Answer (score 13):

Use `respondsToSelector:`.  From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:):

> ### respondsToSelector:
>
> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver implements or inherits a method that can respond to a specified message.
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>   *aSelector* - A selector that identifies a message.
>
> **Return Value**
>   `YES` if the receiver implements or inherits a method that can respond to *aSelector*, otherwise `NO`.

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for [respondsToSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)-

```
if ([foo respondsToSelector: @selector(bar)] {
  [foo bar];
}
```

As [Donal says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732863/objective-c-check-if-a-method-exist/2732906#2732906) the above tells you that foo can *definitely* handle receiving the bar selector. However, if foo's a proxy that forwards bar to some underlying object that will receive the bar message, then respondsToSelector: will tell you NO, even though the message will be forwarded to an object that responds to bar.

Answer (score 1):

Checking selectors with respondsToSelector is normally only for delegate methods.  You shouldn't be using forwardInvocation or proxies for delegate methods.  If you need to use respondsToSelector in other situations you might want to make sure that there isn't a more appropriate way to design your program.

Comment: How do I use respondsToSelector with a delegate?
The delegate is of type id.